# Can the "inducing" vector norm be deduced or "recovered" from an induced norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, reference-request

Can the "inducing" vector norm be deduced or "recovered" from an induced (operator) norm?

This question occurred to me after seeing [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588481/frobenius-norm-is-not-induced).  I'm hoping that perhaps there exists something like the [polarization identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity), i.e. some identity one may use to "recover" the vector norm the same way the polarization identity "recovers" the inner product.

I am aware that any induced norm satisfies the inequality
$$
\left|\|A^r\|\right|^{1/r} \geq \rho(A)
$$
Also, there exists some invertible matrix $S$ such that
$$
\left|\|SAS^{-1}\|\right| = \rho(A)
$$
I'm wondering if one or both of the above might also be a sufficient condition for $\left|\|\cdot \|\right|$ to be a derived norm, and that they might somehow be used to derive some sort of identity producing the necessary vector norm.

Any input is appreciated!

---

*Runaway train of thought below:*

Following HHO's advice (see comment below), here's a neat way to recover the vector norm (assuming that a suitable vector norm does exist):

Let $\|\cdot \|_O$ denote the operator norm.  I will define a vector norm $\|\cdot \|$ as follows: arbitrarily, I set $\|e_1\| = 1$ (because $\alpha \|\cdot\|$ is a vector norm for any $\alpha>0$ and any vector norm $\|\cdot\|$ and since both of these result in the same induced norm, we may set $\|e_1\| = \alpha$ for any $\alpha>0$).  From there, we may define
$$
\|u\| = \left\| u e_1^* \right\|_O = 
\left\| 
\pmatrix{|&|&&|\\
u&0&\cdots&0\\
|&|&&|}
\right\|_O
$$
<s>What remains to be seen is under which conditions this defines a valid vector-norm.</s>

---

In fact, the above must always be a valid vector-norm, by the definition of a matrix norm.  It is necessary to check whether the vector norm produced above induces the operator norm that we started with.

---

By the above, here's a neat criterion for checking whether $\|\cdot\|_O$ is an operator norm:

We can state that $\|\cdot\|_O$ is an induced (matrix) norm if and only if for all $A \in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$, we have
$$
\|A\|_O = \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax e_1^*\|_O}{\|xe_1^*\|_O}
$$
and, presumably, $e_1$ can be replaced by any convenient $v \in \mathbb{F}^n: v^*v = 1$.  I guess I answered my own question then.

Is this a known theorem?  This question is now a reference request.  If anyone has seen something like this, please say so.

Comment: Take a good look at rank one operators … err, matrices … and their norm.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen so with rank one matrices and vector norm $\|\cdot \|$, we have $A = \alpha u v^*$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ and vectors $u,v$ with $\|u\|=\|v\|= 1$. From there, we note that the induced norm $|\|\cdot\||$ satisfies $$\left|\|A\|\right| = \alpha v^*v \frac{\|u\|}{\|v\|} = \alpha v^*v$$ Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: There might be something missing. First, if you plug in the Frobenius norm, you obtain that it is an operator norm, which is not true. Second, what would be a convenient $v$? Last, $|||A|||=\alpha v^*v\frac{\|u\|}{\|v\|}$ does not hold for any induced norm except the 2-norm (and Frobenius norm). Actually, $|||A|||=|\alpha|\|u\|\|v\|_*$, where $\|\cdot\|_*$ is dual to $\|\cdot\|$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel for some reason I had made the assumption that for $A = \alpha u v^*, x = \frac{v}{\|v\|}$ would be the $x$ that attains the maximum $\max_{\|x\| = 1} \|A\|$.  This is clearly not generally the case, certainly not in the infinite dimensional case when this supremum (as I should have it) is not always attained. I will have to rethink this at some point.  Thank you for the input.

Comment: You seem to be assuming norms of square matrices that are induced by a single vector norm? More generally, matrix norms can be induced on arbitrary matrices by specifying separate vector norms on the domain and the codomain.

Comment: @joriki that had been what I originally had in mind, but any partial result would be interesting at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a topological vector space. Let $O(V)$ be the space of continuous operators in $V$, endowed with the [strong operator topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_operator_topology). Assume that $O(V)$ can be given a structure of normed space with the norm $\| \cdot \|$, with the norm generating the strong operator topology of $O(V)$.

Let $f \in V^* \setminus \{ 0 \}$ be a linear and continuous functional. It is easy to show that $v \otimes f$ is a continuous linear operator, since $f$ is so. Define $\| v \| _f = \| v \otimes f \|$. Again, it is easy to show that this is a norm.

Let us show that the topology of $\| \cdot \| _f$ is the same as the original one of $V$. Let $(v_i) _{i \in I}$ be a net convergent to $v$ in the topology of $V$. Then

$$\begin{align} v_i \underset {i \in I} \to v \Leftrightarrow \\
f(u) v_i \underset {i \in I} \to f(u) v \; \forall u \in V \Leftrightarrow \\
(v_i \otimes f) (u) \underset {i \in I} \to (v \otimes f) (u) v \; \forall u \in V \Leftrightarrow \\
v_i \otimes f \underset {i \in I} \to v \otimes f \Leftrightarrow \\
\|v_i \otimes f - v \otimes f \| \underset {i \in I} \to 0 \Leftrightarrow \\ \|(v_i - v) \otimes f \| \underset {i \in I} \to 0 \Leftrightarrow \\
\| v_i - v \| _f \underset {i \in I} \to 0 \; .
\end{align}$$

Finally, let the operator norm $\| \cdot \| _1$ induced on $O(V)$ by $\| \cdot \| _f$ be given by $\| U \| _1 = \sup \{ M>0 | \; \| Uv \| _f \le M \| v \| _f \}$, as usual. Let $U_i \to U$ in this norm. We have $\| (U_i - U)v \| _f \le \|U_i - U \| _1 \| v \| _f$, so $\| (U_i - U)v \| _f \to 0$, so $U_i v \to Uv$ in the original topology of $V$, so $U_i \to U$ in the topology of $O(V)$ and, since this was assumed to be given by $\| \cdot \|$, we obtain $\| U_i - U \| \to 0$, so the topology of $\| \cdot \| _1$ is stronger than the topology of $\| \cdot \|$. I suspect, but cannot prove, that the two topologies do *not* coincide.

Furthermore, if $\| \cdot \|$ has the supplementary property that $\| UV \| \le \| U \| \| V \|$ then we can obtain even more: since $Uv \otimes f = U \circ (v \otimes f)$, then $\| Uv \| _f = \| Uv \otimes f \| = \| U \circ (v \otimes f) \| \le \| U \| \| v \otimes f \| = \| U \| \| v \| _f$, so $\| \cdot \| \le \| \cdot \| _1$. Again, I believe that the opposite inequality does *not* hold, but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: I dont follow the fourth step in your chain of equivalences: Why is $(v_i \otimes f) \to (v \otimes f)$ in the strong operator topology (i.e. pointwise) equivalent to $v_i \otimes f \to v\otimes f$? Do you assume that the norm induces the strong operator topology? Because above you just write "with the topology of O(V) given by ∥⋅∥".

Comment: @PhoemueX: Yes, this is what I meant, but I had formulated it vaguely. I have reformulated it now.