# Is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of a matrix induced from a vector norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

A general way to get a matrix norm is inducing it from a vector norm.

The question is, can the Hilbert-Schmidt norm obtained this way?

As a norm general question, is every matrix norm obtained this way?

The crucial condition is $\|XY\| \leq \|X\|\,\|Y\|$.

Comment: I remembered after posting my question that [this has been asked before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588481/frobenius-norm-is-not-induced)

Comment: [this is a related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588575/can-the-inducing-vector-norm-be-deduced-or-recovered-from-an-induced-norm) that yours reminds me of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hilbert Schmidt norm *cannot* be obtained as an induced norm.  Of the Schatten-$p$ norms, only the $\infty$ norm (which is also the induced $2$-norm) is an induced norm.

A quick way to see that the Hilbert Schmidt norm is not induced by any matrix norm is to note that the identity matrix $I$ satisfies $\|I\| > 1$.